# Flagging a question for migration

Tags: discussion, flagging

On reviewing the question, [How can I solve syntax error for the following code in Python 2.7?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4148/how-can-i-solve-syntax-error-for-the-following-code-in-python-2-7), it seemed to myself, and others, that it should be migrated to StackOverflow.

When flagging a question to be off topic because it belongs to another Stack Exchange, you can only choose the 3D Printing Meta.  Why?

> [image: Migration flagging dialog]

Comment: There was another question that I wanted to suggest be migrated to the Engineering SE and was unable to do that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the flag "In need of moderation attention" and then specify why it should be migrated and where to. It doesn't always work, depending on the length of time that the question has been posted for and some other factors, but often it does work.

The answer to "Why?" is simply because it hasn't been set up by the moderators. Generally, a specific migration "pathway" has to be agreed between sites, I think, and only then is that particular SE site *manually added* as an option to the migration dialog. There is a post, from a few years ago, on SE.Arduino - See [Why does the migrate dialog only list Arduino Meta?](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2340/why-does-the-migrate-dialog-only-list-arduino-meta).

Actually, I was mistaken, although, I am sure that I heard the above from someone, somewhere. Apparently, it is because SE 3D Printing is still in beta:

> I think it is because we are "only" a Beta site. Once we graduate, I
>   think more migrating options become available.
>
> As a moderator, I can migrate to other sites, and have done in some
>   cases. I usually ask their moderators first, and quite often they
>   decline to accept them. However migration does happen.
>
> I think there is some rule that Beta sites don't get to migrate to
>   other sites. I'm not quite sure why such a rule exists (it would seem
>   more logical for it to be the other way).

See also, from SE Robotics, [Closing a question - only option for another site is Robotics Meta](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/closing-a-question-only-option-for-another-site-is-robotics-meta).

> #### Migrating to an arbitrary stack exchange site
>
> This is only an option for ♦ moderators, so instead of voting to close
>   the question <sup>†</sup> you should flag it for moderator
>   attention <sup>‡</sup> with a suggestion of where it should be
>   migrated.
>
> On established sites, migration paths are created to allow migration
>   without moderator approval, but any migrations outside of those
>   pathways still have to be handled by a moderator. The reason for this
>   is because...
>
> #### This specific question
>
> This question would not be a good candidate for migration. We try not
>   to migrate questions which would just be closed on the target site for
>   another reason. In this case, it is a very broad question. It could be
>   edited to be a more *[practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems faced](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* but
>   that may invalidate the existing answer, which is pretty good, given
>   the limitations of the question.
>
> If neither [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) nor [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) want this
>   question, I'm happy for it to remain on *robitics*, since there are
>   robotic applications of the answer to this question.
>
> † <sub>*close > off-topic because... > This question belongs on
>   another site in the Stack Exchange network*</sub>
>
> ‡ <sub>*flag >  in need of moderator intervention*</sub>

See also [What are the limitations in Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296832/what-are-the-limitations-in-beta), in particular [animuson's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296832/what-are-the-limitations-in-beta#answer-296833):

> Beta sites don't have default migration paths (although moderators can still migrate to/from).

Comment: I figured that; but, if there is a specific response that says it needs to be migrated to another Stack Exchange, why doesn't it allow the selection of other Stack Exchanges?

Comment: Thanks for the work-around; but, it doesn't answer the question - 'Why?'

Comment: @markshancock - Ah, sorry. The answer to that is simply because it hasn't been set up by the moderators. Generally a specific migration "pathway" has to be agreed between sites, I think, and only then is that particular SE site is manually added as an option to the migration dialog. There is a post from a few years ago on SE.Arduino - I think I asked the same question (but it may have been in a comment). I'll try to dig out a link.

Comment: @markshancock - Bingo! See [Why does the migrate dialog only list Arduino Meta?](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2340/why-does-the-migrate-dialog-only-list-arduino-meta).

Comment: @markshancock, sorry for the late response. It seems like Greensonline is right, and for now, flagging seems like a good solution. :-)

Comment: @Greenonline, would you want the add a reference to [What are the limitations in Beta(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296832/what-are-the-limitations-in-beta)?  SE won't allow me to submit a suggested edit.

Comment: @markshancock - done :-)